# Retain values in all pages with session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, browser-cache

I have 10 page with pagination.I am listing 10 data per page.While clicking on pagination button it will go to database and fetching records accordingly.Each data having one button(checked/notchecked),I want to retain the state of the button after page refresh.

Consider the following scenario:

I am choosing first 2 button from a first page(now state of that two changed to checked).It should be retain even after page refresh.What is the best optimal solution without storing the state in database. Is it possible to do in javascript/jquery with jsons?

Suggest some optimal solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We can correct suggestions but we don't do the work for you.

Comment: I am trying to use javascript.push/pop in array.Its working perfect for a single page.Could not able to retain the values in next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize array holding that information (what is checked and what's not) and store it in cookie or PHP session.